# how to remove previously committed file from git repo?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I accidentally committed a large zip file and pushed to bitbucket.

Now, I have already added the file to `.gitignore` and use `git rm --cached` to remove it and committed the deletion of the file.

But when I `git checkout` previous commit, the large zip file is still there. Meaning it's still in the git repo.

How can I remove this large zip file completely ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many commits have been added to the branch since the commit containing the large binary file?  The easiest option might be to amend that commit, and remove the file.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just one. the 2nd last commit added the large file. the last commit remove the large file.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hmm.. how to amend? by using `git revert` ?

Comment: you need do `git rebase` to rewrite commit history, see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History for how to do it. maybe `git filter-branch` fit  your question more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: @JulienLopez Perhaps not an exact duplicate here, because he might be able to simply get away with using `git commit --amend` .

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Agreed, I haven't paid attention to the comments, your solution should be enough in this case. The possible dup is related anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you only have one commit on top of the commit containing the large binary file, you might be able to avoid an interactive rebase.

First, nuke the second commit you made removing the large binary file:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

This leaves you in exactly the state you were when you had just committed the large binary file.

Now, at this point the large binary file should again appear locally.  Delete this file, then add that change to the index if Git has not already done that for you.

Finally, *amend* the bad commit via:

```
git commit --amend
```

To push this branch to Bitbucket you will have to force push because you rewrote the history:

```
git push --force origin feature
```

Keep in mind that force pushing *rewrites* the remote history, which can cause problems for anyone else sharing this branch.  In your case, the benefits of doing this probably outweight having an enormous binary being part of your history.

Comment: This seems great if the commit you nuke only added the large binary file. If it did anything else too `git reset --hard HEAD~1` will lose it. Wouldn't `git reset HEAD~1` without `--hard` be safer?

Comment: yes @dumbledad other files are committed together with the large binary file

Comment: @dumbledad The commit I suggest nuking only removes the large binary file AFAIK, so no real work would be lost.  Then, the remaining commit is _amended_ after the binary has been deleted from the file system.

Comment: i am testing this out. Thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Definitely read [git reset demystified](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified) before using that `--hard` option often.

Answer (score 0):

The safest and probably cleanest way to go is to rebase interactively.

```
git rebase -i HEAD^^
```

Or,

```
git rebase -i your-commit-no^
```

From there you can squash commits, which puts one or more commits together into the previous commit. To completely delete a commit from the history, delete the line from the list.

You can revert a commit with

```
git revert
```

but its going to add more commit messages to the history, which may be undesirable. Use the -n parameter to tell Git not to commit the revert right away. You can rebase interactively and squash those on up to a previous commmit to keep things clean.

If the two commits you're working with here affect the same file(s), you may see a merge conflict.

Resetting the repository with

```
git reset --hard
```

should be done with care, as it cannot be undone.

Rewriting history should be done with care.

Comment: He would still probably be removing the HEAD commit, even in an interactive rebase.

Comment: `git revert` keeps the commit (and the large file) in history.